# ImageMagick-6.8.0-4-Q16-windows-dll.exe is not able to convert PDF to image

Tags: php, pdf, image-processing, imagemagick, windows-8.1

> OS : Windows 8
>  PHP Configuration : ZSCE
>  Image Magick Version
>   : 6.8.6-9-Q16-x64-dll
>  Ghost Script Version : gs910w64

I have installed `ImageMagick-6.8.6-9-Q16-x64-dll.exe` on Windows 8.1 system. I am able to convert PDF to Jpeg image on command line but not able to convert PDF to Image from PHP Script.

Does anybody has idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sorted out the issue after long time. What I was doing is I was installing 64 bit version of ImageMagick and GhostScript in my Windows 8 operating system whereas my Apache (ZSCE) installation itself is a 32 bit. So IM and GS were not able to work. Then I installed 32 bit version of both IM and GS and now everything is working fine.

So for a quick solution.

> Identify which type of Bit Apache support?
>   Then installed its relevant version of IM and GS.
>   First Install IM and then GS.

**Previous Installation:


I previously installed IM and GS were 64 bit


Solution


Installed 32 bit version of IM and GS (regardless of Operating System processing bit 64 in my case for Windows 8).
 Should install ?? bit version of IM and GS which Apache's version.**

That's it. Now your conversion from PDF to Image should work.
Cheers !!!